# IMAGE_INSTALL vs PACKAGE_FEATURES - what's the difference?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, recipe

I am trying to create my own customized linux image and I am trying to figure out how to install packages I need and found that there were multiple ways of installing packages.

I read through the yoctoproject manual and read through definitions of 'IMAGE_INSTALL' and 'FEATURE_PACKAGES' in which IMAGE_INSTALL 'specifies the packages to install into an image through image.bbclass' and FEATURE_PACKAGES 'Defines one or more packages to include in an image'. I have seen both used in the core-image.bbclass file and both use packagegroup-* so it's still unclear which is appropriate to use for what *kinds* of package installs.

Any human explanation of the difference between the two and what each is intended to be used for?

Comment: `FEATURE_PACKAGES` is intended to use in conjunction with `IMAGE_FEATURES`, as when an image feature xxx is enable, corresponding packages defined in `FEATURE_PACKAGES_xxx` are added to image.

Comment: hmm so FEATURE_PACKAGES_<featurename> would only be installed if the <featurename> is enabled? Not sure if i am following. And if so - how does that differ from IMAGE_INSTALL? Does IMAGE_INSTALL install packages no matter what?

Comment: For instance, there is a `package-management` image feature that gather every needed to handle rpm/apt-get/... So it probably defines something like `FEATURE_PACKAGES_package-management = " rpm"`, so when you set this feature in your image recipe with `IMAGE_FEATURES = "package-management"`, it will install `rpm`. You could also add `rpm` by hand with `IMAGE_INSTALL = "rpm"`.

Comment: See @Nayfe's comment, but use IMAGE_INSTALL and packagegroups to drive actually populating your specific packages. Use FEATURE_PACKAGES when you define certain features your target may have.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer from [@Nayfe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6225741/nayfe) :

`IMAGE_INSTALL` is used if you want to install any and all packages.

`FEATURE_PACKAGES` is only used if you want to install packages if a `FEATURE` is enabled through the use of `IMAGE_FEATURES`.

**Original Comment:**

`FEATURE_PACKAGES` is intended to use in conjunction with `IMAGE_FEATURES`, as when an image feature `xxx` is enabled, corresponding packages defined in `FEATURE_PACKAGES_xxx` are added to image.